# Does `close(fd)` destroy the file table entry and/or the vnode table entry?

Tags: c, linux, unix, io, kernel

In Unix

```
#include <unistd.h>
int close(int fd);
```

- Is it correct that `close(fd)` must also destroy  the file table entry associated with `fd`? Yes, even if there is another file descriptor referring to the same file table entry?
- Does `close(fd)` also destroy the vnode table entry associated with the vnode table entry, or not necessarily? Yes, even if there is another file table entry referring to the same vnode table entry?

Thanks.

For "process file descriptor table", "(kernel) file  table", "vnode", see http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/fall04/os/c18/

Note: My question comes from APUE.  I am actually interested in Linux, but Linux doesn't have vnode, but general inode structure. So for "vnode" still to apply, I have to ask for Unix.

Answer (score 4):

`close` closes the file *descriptor*. If that descriptor is the last one referring to the corresponding *open file description*, then the latter will be closed, which might entail further side effects. This is in terms of the modern meaning of Unix, in terms of the Single Unix Specification/POSIX.

I'm not sure what vnode means; I assume it's part of one historical unix and has some correspondence to open file descriptions.

Comment: Thanks. In "If that descriptor is the last one referring to the corresponding open file description", what do you mean by "descriptor" and "open file description"?

Comment: When you open a file (or create a socket, accept a connection, etc.), a new *open file description* is created. It carries properties like the current seek position, whether it's set to non-blocking or append mode (the flags you can set with `fcntl`'s `F_SETFL`), etc. A file *descriptor* is just a number that serves as a process-local handle referencing the open file description (OFD). Calling `dup`, `fork`ing, etc. create situations where more than one fd refers to the same OFD.

Comment: @Tim a file can be access by more that one file descriptor. For exemple one can duplicate with dup a file descriptor.

Comment: @R.. Thanks. If that descriptor is NOT the last one referring to the corresponding open file description, then what will happen? Does `close` do nothing?

Comment: @Tim It doesn't do anything _to the open file description_ except maybe decrement a reference count.  But it does invalidate the _file descriptor_ and make that descriptor number available for use by a subsequent `dup`, `open`, `pipe`, `socket`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may assume that the following functions from the standard library: `open, read, write, seek` and `close`, form an *interface* to the operating system. In that interface it maintains some data structures. Those data structures are of no interest to the user of the standard library.

The functions mentioned do not operate on the file system. Hence no vnodes or inodes are modified by these functions. They will be operated on/modified by the filesystem part of the operating system, if such modification is required by the operations. For example, writing may require new blocks on disk to be allocated, which must be registered in an inode.

The `unlink` function of the standard library instructs the operating system to remove a file. If the OS can remove the file (i.e. it is not protected, is not open by another process, etc.) it will remove the file from the filesystem, thus modifying inodes. (Filesystems with lazy deletes move the file to a recycle bin).

So: it is *not* correct that `close(fd)` also destroys the file table entry associated with `fd`, if with "file table entry" you mean the entry in the filesystem, except possibly for short lived, temporary files (however, those may never have had an entry anyway, depending on the filesystem software of the OS),

and: no, `close(fd)` does *not* destroy "the vnode table entry associated with the vnode table entry" (which is strange sentence anyway ), if with vnode you mean some type of inode.

---

EDIT:

With reference to your course material:

> Is it correct that close(fd) must also destroy the file table entry associated with fd? Yes, even if there is another file descriptor referring to the same file table entry?

No, that is not correct. `close` will destroy the entry in the Process File Descriptor Table of the process. The Kernel File Table must maintain a reference count (not shown in your course material) and when that gets to zero, the entry of the KFT can be deleted. So the `close` causes only the reference count in the KFT to be decremented.

> Does `close(fd)` also destroy the vnode table entry associated with the vnode table entry, or not necessarily? Yes, even if there is another file table entry referring to the same vnode table entry?

I find this question not relevant or I don't understand it. There is no vnode table entry. There is only a vnode identifier in the KFT. Managing vnodes (i.e. storage allocation and deallocation) is beyond the scope of your course.

Comment: Thanks, but you missed the meanings of file table entry and vnode. For "process file descriptor table", "(kernel) file  table", "vnode", see http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/fall04/os/c18/

Comment: @Tim: That's one possible implementation (from BSD, I think) but it is not universal. Other unix-likes might use slightly different datastructures, giving them very different names. Posix does not standardise anything except the values returned by `stat` (or `fstat`).

Comment: Tim, whether vnode, inode, fat or ntfs: they are file systems with which the standard library interfaces. You have nothing to with what happens in the filesystem, except be assured your function calls will be reliable executed.

Comment: Tim, I followed your link and tried to give some answers.